# Tricky PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I used stripe to return a Customer Object. I want to extract the bank account ID and save it in a database for later use. What is the proper syntax to access the array properly?

Here is what I have tried:

```
$bank_account=$customer->lastResponse['json']['sources']['data'][0]['id'];
```

I was told to try:

```
$bank_account=$customer->bank_accounts->data[0]['id'];
```

But that came up null as well...

Im not sure how to work with the object or what the right way to do this is.
I need the `bank_account_id`
This is what the `var_dump($customer)` looks like after some formatting and removing information that is not pertinent. I think I can either use a JSON decode or access the array called 'json' i dont know the proper syntax for either of those solutions. Help please (:

```
object(Stripe\Customer)#3572 (6) 
{ 
    ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#3576 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(1) { ["Stripe-Account"]=> string(21) "acct_1BNn74AprSj6yALS" } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "secretkey" } 
    ["_values":protected]=> array(15) {//Removed For brevity} 
    ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#3590 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#3602 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } 
    ["_lastResponse":protected]=> 
        object(Stripe\ApiResponse)#3714 (4) 
        { 
            ["headers"]=> array(15) { //Removed for brevity} 
            // Json
            ["body"]=> string(1148) "{
                "id": "cus_BoJOjFghfV7mmq", "object": "customer", "account_balance": 0, "created": 1511290036, "currency": null, "default_source": "bank_account_id", "delinquent": false, "description": "Name", "discount": null, "email": null, "livemode": true, "metadata": {}, "shipping": null, "sources": { "object": "list", "data": [ { "id": "bank_account_id", "object": "bank_account", "account_holder_name": "Daniel Taylor", "account_holder_type": "individual", "bank_name": "Bank Name", "country": "US", "currency": "usd", "customer": "cus_id", "fingerprint": "info", "last4": "last four of account", "metadata": {}, "routing_number": "routing number", "status": "new" } ], "has_more": false, "total_count": 1, "url": "/v1/customers/cus_BoJOjFghfV7mmq/sources" }, "subscriptions": { "object": "list", "data": [], "has_more": false, "total_count": 0, "url": "/v1/customers/cus_BoJOjFghfV7mmq/subscriptions" } 
            } " 
            ["json"]=> array(15) 
            { 
                ["id"]=> string(18) "cus_id" 
                ["object"]=> string(8) "customer" 
                ["account_balance"]=> int(0) 
                ["created"]=> int(1511290036) 
                ["currency"]=> NULL 
                ["default_source"]=> string(27) "bank_account_id" 
                ["delinquent"]=> bool(false) 
                ["description"]=> string(13) "Name" 
                ["discount"]=> NULL 
                ["email"]=> NULL ["livemode"]=> bool(true) 
                ["metadata"]=> array(0) { } 
                ["shipping"]=> NULL 
                ["sources"]=> array(5) 
                { 
                    ["object"]=> string(4) "list" 
                    ["data"]=> array(1) 
                    { 
                        [0]=> array(13) 
                        {
                            ["id"]=> string(27) "bank_account_id" ["object"]=> string(12) "bank_account" 
                            ["account_holder_name"]=> string(13) "name" 
                            ["account_holder_type"]=> string(10) "individual" 
                            ["bank_name"]=> string(26) "Bank Name" 
                            ["country"]=> string(2) "US" ["currency"]=> string(3) "usd" 
                            ["customer"]=> string(18) "cus_ID" 
                            ["fingerprint"]=> string(16) "fingerprint" 
                            ["last4"]=> string(4) "lastfour" ["metadata"]=> array(0) { } 
                            ["routing_number"]=> string(9) "routenumber" 
                            ["status"]=> string(3) "new" 
                        } 
                    } 
                    ["has_more"]=> bool(false) 
                    ["total_count"]=> int(1) 
                    ["url"]=> string(40) "/v1/customers/cus_BoJOjFghfV7mmq/sources" 
                } 
                ["subscriptions"]=> array(5) { ["object"]=> string(4) "list" ["data"]=> array(0) { } ["has_more"]=> bool(false) ["total_count"]=> int(0) ["url"]=> string(46) "/v1/customers/cus_id/subscriptions" } 
            } 
            ["code"]=> int(200) 
        } 
}
```

Comment: @kchason The Stripe API returns the object already decoded.

Comment: The Stripe API documentation is at https://stripe.com/docs/api/php

Comment: `_lastResponse` has a leading undersore (`_`) and is an object. Because it is an object, `json` (which is a terrible name for this, BTW) is a property of it, not an index in an array. You want: `$customer->_lastResponse->json['sources']['data'][0]['id']`

Comment: The `_lastResponse` value is protected, and probably cannot be directly accessed. If this is not a value provided by the api, you may be able to hack it using `ReflectionClass`, but if you find yourself having to do this, you are usually using the object wrong, and should use a different identifier.

Comment: Good catch on the protected property. Time for the OP to read some docs...

Comment: Your other option would be to extend `Customer`, and expose the value you need as `public`. Hopefully stripe provides a way to do this without hacking their library.

Comment: There's no need for any hacking. All the documented properties are accessible using property accessors.

Comment: You **really** need to read the documentation. The bank account ID will be returned to you when you create it, so save it then. Failing that the API has an endpoint for returning just bank account details, theres no need to use a customer object.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
$bank_account = $customer->sources->data[0]->id
```

If the customer has multiple fund sources, you may need to loop through the `data` array to find the one you want. `$customer->sources->data[$i]->object` will be `"bank_account"` for the source you want.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure there is a getter in there. You can just use the properties you would expect on the object.

Example:

```
$customer_id = $customer->id;
$bank_account_id = $customer->sources->data[0]->id;
```